# $x^2(x+y)^2+y^2(y+z)^2+z^2(x+z)^2+2 x y(x+y)(y+z) +2 y z(y+z)(x+z)+2 x z(x+y)(x+z) \geq 12 x y z(x+y+z)$

Tags: inequality

I was solving a problem and I got the following inequality left:

> $$x^2(x+y)^2+y^2(y+z)^2+z^2(x+z)^2+2 x y(x+y)(y+z) +2 y z(y+z)(x+z)+2 x z(x+y)(x+z) \geq 12 x y z(x+y+z)$$ for positive real $x,y,z$

---

First I noticed that the inequality is homogeneous, so I took $x+y+z=1$, getting a new inequality $$x^2(x+y)^2+y^2(y+z)^2+z^2(x+z)^2+2 x y(x+y)(y+z) +2 y z(y+z)(x+z)+2 x z(x+y)(x+z) \geq 12 x y z$$ Now I tried replacing values of terms like $(x+y)^2 = (1-z)^2$ but it only became complex. Another approach I thought of was applying AM GM on the whole expression, but it will generate a sixth root, which would create problem. I also noticed the LHS is $[x(x+y)+y(y+z)+z(x+z)]^2]$
How do I proceed?

Comment: The pqr method works well.

Comment: @RiverLi what's the pqr method?

Comment: The pqr method is to use the substitution $p = x + y + z, q = xy + yz + zx, r = xyz$ to express the inequality in terms of $p, q, r$; Then use the well-known inequalities (in terms of $p, q, r$; e.g., $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \ge ab + bc + ca$ is written as $p^2 \ge 3q$) to prove the desired inequality. For example, here, the desired inequality is written as $p^4-2p^2q-12pr+q^2\ge 0$.